# SOLR boost near words and in the correct order

Tags: apache, solr

how can I use tokenzier oder factories in Apache SOLR to boost my search results that match the query with near words and in the correct order to get a higher score? I want these to appear higher in the search results.

An example: 
My query is "samsung galaxy s5".

In my results I want an ordering of this or a close one:

- "Samsung Galaxy S5" // exact match
- "Samsung S5 Galaxy" // only two words switched
- "Samsung Galaxy black S5" // words not near
- "Samsung black S5 Galaxy" // words not near and switched

Comment: did you try boosting..like title:samsung galaxy s5^10 OR (title:samsung galaxy)^5.0 OR title:samsung S5 galaxy^2...something like this

Comment: Yes this could be possible on the Solr Admin. But since the Solr server is running for a webshop, manipulations on the query should be done in solrconfig.xml and schema.xml

Comment: yes...you can modify the same in solrconfig.xml..or you can modify the place where you are building the query...that may be at your application side..

Comment: ok but how can I boost it in the solrconfig.xml the way you said? All I have are the definitions from all fields and how to boost specific fields or not?

Comment: its not possible through solrconfig.xml...you have to do it at application end

Answer (score 1):

Try the Dismax or EDismax query parser with a phrase. Even if you only search one field, dismax provides a few extra features around phrase matching that will probably give you what you want.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser